# Web Component - Sizing

Tags: css, size, web-component

When I create Web Components the default size is `0x0`, despite containing elements.
For example here my element is `0x0`:

[image: Custom Element width,height = 0,0]

But when I hover over the button contained within then you can see the button does have a width and height:

[image: Hovever child element does have size]

So my question is how can I make the custom element the same size as the child element?
Why does this happen?
I suspect it is due to the shador DOM and `<slot>`, but surly there must be a trick to give the custom element the correct height?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you create a SO snippet, JSFiddle or CodePen , I can't reproduce this behavior with a button in a slot. What version of FireFox are you using? Your first screenshot shows the  Console Tab before the Inspector; in evergreen FF its the other way around

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment, you inspired me to create [an example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-4bjeqq?file=src%2Findex.js)... The fault was mine, the `<slot>` is inside an absolutely positioned `<div>` inside the shadow root... Silly me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created [an example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-4bjeqq?file=src%2Findex.js)... The fault was mine, the `<slot>` is inside an absolutely positioned `<div>` inside the shadow root... Silly me!

Comment: and ``Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children)`` can become ``[...this.children]``

Answer (score 1):

By default, custom elements aren't blocks. You need to explicitly set `display: block;` property in CSS, like this:

```css
juel-menu {
  display: block;
}
```